# Rear Coil Spring perch for Golf MK5 GTi - what part number?

Tags: suspension, golf, part-identification, parts, gti

According to the diagram at https://workshop-manuals.com/volkswagen/golf-mk5/running_gear_axles_steering/rear_suspension_drive_shaft/assembly_overview_shock_absorber_coil_spring_(front-wheel_drive)/ (parts 1 and 3) there are rubber perches at the top and bottom of my rear coil springs. It's also pictured at 
https://cdn4.pelicanparts.com/techarticles/Volkswagen_Golf_GTI_Mk_V/125-SUSPEN-Replacing_Rear_Springs/images_small/pic06.jpg

I'm replacing the springs and, especially if these are rubber, want to replace these too.

Where can I find the part numbers? I've been googling for ages now and can't find these for the Mk5 anywhere at all? Am I missing something?

Huge appreciation for any help.

Comment: What is the year and engine size of your car?

Comment: It's a GTI Mk5 so will be a 2.0l Turbo.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a dealer - they will have the part number. You may find that the pattern parts suppliers don't list it so don't have a number for it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can find online, the part number for the upper spring pad is 1K0 512 149 B and the lower is 1K0 512 297 C.